# Contemporary Evangelical human nature positions that are different than St. Augustine

Tags: comparative-christianity, evangelicalism, augustine, nature-of-man

St. Augustine's theology is highly embedded in Western Christian denominations today, including among Evangelicals.  But I'm sure his theology is not the only one supported by the Bible.  In other words, there are other legitimate theological options that modern Evangelicals can choose today even though they are not Augustinian, while still respecting [*sola scriptura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura) and the [*rule of faith*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Faith).

As Evangelical theologians became more self-aware of the church fathers influence on even very established doctrines such as the Trinity (now considering [Social Trinitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_trinitarianism) for example) more options become available, especially if the Augustinian option was too much linked with Neo-Platonism.  More awareness with the Ancient Near East and Second Temple Literature also contribute to exploring more Biblically aligned options, for example moving away from soul-body dualism to a more Hebraic view of the human person as a highly integrated substance.

One of St. Augustine's most valued contribution is his integration of Christianity with all aspects of *human nature*: composition, evil, freedom, morality, happiness, etc.  I'm interested in contemporary evangelical human nature positions that are formulated *differently* than St. Augustine, which include one or more of the following aspects:

- **Composition of the Human soul**: *imago Dei*, philosophy of mind, neuroscience, psychology, existentialism, romanticism
- **Evil**: how the human soul is affected by demonology, possession, sin, etc.
- **Freedom**: as connected with providence, foreknowledge, etc.
- **Morality**: as connected with virtues, happiness, beatitude, meaning of life, etc.
- **Spirituality**: prayer, beatific vision, theosis, ascetic disciplines, spiritual exercises

**Question**: I'm looking for **contemporary Evangelical human nature positions that are different than St. Augustine, attested by published / credentialed theologians in their books, journals, or blogs**.

Excellent example sources for those differences are:

- [New Studies in Biblical Theology](https://www.ivpress.com/new-studies-in-biblical-theology)
- [New Studies in Dogmatics](https://zondervanacademic.com/blog/nsd)
- [Counterpoints series](https://zondervanacademic.com/products/category/counter-points)